# Extends and Exceptions

Tags: java

My professor gave me this in class today. He didn't elaborate too much on it and I was hoping that someone could help me figure it out/what I need to do.

---

```
MyDate

Constructor myDate(int month, int day, int year)
  throws myDateException {   }


MyDateException extends Exception

MyMonthException extends MyDateException

MyDayException extends MyDateException

MyYearException extends MyDateException
```

---

Can someone please explain "extends" and "throws"? Thanks

EDIT: For clarification, I never asked for you to solve it for me, just help steer me in the right direction. And yes, this was all we were given in an email.

Comment: You're giving us the hint and we have to give you the assignment? It works the other way around man..

Comment: Could it be you who "didn't evaluate too much" ?

Comment: No, this is literally all we are given. I'm sorry that it's not a lot.

Comment: This might be the code you are given, but that's not the assignment you were given. I won't believe that he never told you what to do or what he's expecting. Have you asked classmates? Or the professor?

Comment: Nope...this is what was it. Emailed this to everyone, said due tomorrow....Not the best prof out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throws` is used to 'launch' an exception (ie error) : [documentation about java exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

`extends` is the keyword for inheritance between classes : [documentation about java inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

an `exception` is thrown when an error occurs

`extends` means that the class can basically do everything the class it extends.

Answer (score 0):

`extends` mean that the class is an extension or subclass. This class inherits all of it's parent's attributes, properties, and methods.

`throws` indicates that a method may throw a specific exception(s). This generally indicates an error that is recoverable.